# Using the paypal asp.net SDK for credit card processing only

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal, credit-card

I am trying to use paypal simply to handle my credit card transactions.  I have a C# based asp.net application that collects the users information and calculates the total charge.  I simply want to use the paypal asp.net sdk to pass the billing information and the total cost to paypal for processing but cannot find any examples in the sdk on how to do this.  I'm not sure exactly where to begin, I've looked into both the SDK AP and AA solutions from the paypal samples but neither seem to do things as simply as what I need.  Essentially I'm looking for the first step in the right direction for this process.

Comment: If you are looking the latest solution, checkout this demo --> https://techtolia.com/PayPal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've put out some blog posts on how to do this, including how to handle the "form" problem:

http://codersbarn.com/?tag=/paypal

Check the PayPal documentation for the parameters to be passed.